# Merge/concatenate rows containing duplicate ids and TRUE/FALSE values, retaining only TRUE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

Given a dataframe

```
{'id': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 101, 3: 101, 4: 102},
 'A': {0: True, 1: False, 2: True, 3: False, 4: True},
 'B': {0: False, 1: True, 2: False, 3: True, 4: False},
 'C': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False}}
```

which looks like this

[image]

How do we merge rows so that there is only one row for each unique id, retaining all True values?

Goal:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby.max`:

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).max()
```

Comment: What if there are other columns in addition to 'id' that are not TRUE/FALSE? e.g. 'date'. If I do this operation, it doesn't remove duplicates due to this additional column.

Comment: Probably a problem with my particular dataframe. Extending the simplified dataframe I included here, I tried `df.groupby(['id', 'D', 'E'], as_index=False).max()`, where D and E contain arbitrary values, e.g. string, that are duplicates for each unique id. I was able to merge rows based on only True/False columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
out = df.groupby('id').max().reset_index()
```

Since

```
True > False
return : True
```